# Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output

Tags: c, android-ndk, cmake, java-native-interface

I am trying to use NDK to link a C project to Android Studio. I get the following Cmake error. I get the same error with any project that uses NDK.

Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/android-ndk/audio-echo/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

```
Run Build Command:"C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.3155560\bin\ninja.exe" "cmTC_52340"

[1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_52340.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
[2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_52340

FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -isystem C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as -mthumb -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a --sysroot C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a -LC:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc -pie -fPIE CMakeFiles/cmTC_52340.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTC_52340  -lm && cd ."

The system cannot find the path specified.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I am using Windows 10 and Android Studio 2.3.3.
I can successfully run the same program on another Windows 10 machine.
I would love to understand at least what part of this is failing. Any input is appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you do a `dir C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe`?

Comment: So I moved my sdk directory because cmd had issues finding the toolchains directory. Now when I execute dir C:\....\clang.exe I get:

 Volume in drive C is Windows8_OS
 Volume Serial Number is CE7B-444C

 Directory of C:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin

06/07/2017  08:22 AM        55,872,512 clang.exe
               1 File(s)     55,872,512 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  68,679,270,400 bytes free

Comment: That looks good. What happens when you try to execute `C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchain‌​s\llvm\prebuilt\wind‌​ows-x86_64\bin\clang‌​.exe` from the command line now? And does the CMake still fail?

Comment: I had to re download ndk separately in order for cmd to recognize the toolchains folder. Now when I run clang.exe from its full path I get:

clang.exe: error: no input files.

btw thanks for your input this is a huge road block for me at the moment.

Comment: That's great progress. What happens when you run CMake now?

Comment: Dude I appreciate your effort but me and my associates have decided to ditch NDK and re-write everything in Java. There's just not enough eewanco's to help us with all of our cmake issues, and boy are there a ton of cmake issues. http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/35rz5y

Answer (score 0):

The error "The system cannot find the path specified." is issued by `cmd.exe` (that is, the Windows 10 command interpreter). CMake is invoking `cmd.exe` and asking it to run `C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchain‌​s\llvm\prebuilt\wind‌​ows-x86_64\bin\clang‌​.exe`, but `cmd.exe` cannot find it, presumably because it doesn't exist. This suggests that NDK may not be installed properly, or at all. Use Windows Explorer or `cmd` to look for the existence of this file; if it doesn't exist, your tools aren't installed properly. See where things went awry; for example, if `C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchain‌​s\llvm\prebuilt\wind‌​ows-x86_64\bin` exists and has other files in it, perhaps something got corrupt.  If you can't even find `ndk-bundle`, NDK is probably not installed at all.

If the file exists, try executing it; go into `cmd` and run `C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchain‌​s\llvm\prebuilt\wind‌​ows-x86_64\bin\clang‌​.exe` directly. If it works, there is something wrong with your CMake environment (not sure what), but I'm guessing it won't work.

Comment: Thanks a ton this is very helpful. I'm unable to access the toolchains folder via cmd. I can get as far as ndk-bundle but it can't find toolchains after that. Although, I can navigate my way there in the file explorer.